# Neo4j 1 to 1 Relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two nodes, "client" and "builder". I want to find only the relationships where the client only has 1 builder, and that builder only has that one client so a 1-1 relationship. So far my query is

```
MERGE(b:Person{name:csv.name) 
MERGE(c:Person{name:csv.name})
WITH collect(distinct b) as builder, collect(distinct c) as client
UNWIND builder as builders
UNWIND client as clients
WITH builders, clients
WHERE builders = 1 and clients = 1
MATCH (builders:Person)-[bu:builder_for]->(clients:Person)
WITH builders,clients, count(distinct bu) as builds
WHERE builds=1

RETURN distinct builders, clients
```

This only returns though a 1 to many relationship and is still showing duplicates in my client list.

[The highlighted are the ones I would want to return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCdCS.png)

**UPDATE** cybersam implementation worked, thank you so much!

Comment: Are the `b` and `c` nodes supposed to have the same set of names (`csv.name`)?

Comment: @cybersam no, they each have their own set of names. Sorry typo on my part when creating the question, it is MERGE(c:Person{name:csv.client}).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to get *all* the `builder`/`client` pairs that only have a single `builder_for` relationship between them, this query uses the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COUNT` to do that:

```
MATCH (builder:Person)-[rel:builder_for]->(client:Person)
WITH builder, client, COUNT(rel) AS rel_count
WHERE rel_count = 1
RETURN builder, client;
```

[UPDATE]

If, instead, you want `builder`/`client` pairs in which the `builder` has only that one `client`, and vice versa, then this query should work:

```
MATCH (builder:Person)
WHERE SIZE((builder)-[:builder_for]->()) = 1
MATCH (builder)-[:builder_for]->(client:Person)
WHERE SIZE(()-[:builder_for]->(client)) = 1
RETURN builder, client;
```

This query uses efficient relationship degree-ness checks (in the `WHERE` clauses) to ensure that the `builder` and `client` nodes only have, respectively, a single outgoing or incoming `builder_for` relationship.

Comment: Doing this query still produced all of the nodes for both the builder and the client that have more than 1 builder_for relationship.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data that shows that? That should be impossible, given how aggregating functions work. (Or, do you want to treat the relationship in a non-directional way?)

Comment: i added a picture example to my question

Comment: See my uodated answer